# python programming define a Loop that ask for names, numbers, and numbers to skip

Tags: python, loops, count

Loop that ask for names, numbers, and numbers to skip.
Enter your name: Alex
Input your starting number: 5
What number do you want to skip: 3
Do you have more numbers to skip (Y/N): Yes
Please only input Y or N.
Do you have more number to skip (Y/N): Y
What number do you want to skip: 1
Do you have more numbers to skip (Y/N): N
Alex is starting to count from 5.
Start!
5... 4... 2... 0!

My Code are below but I think anyone may change it because my code looks not so good:

```
text = input("Enter your name: ")
print(text)
text1 = input("Input your starting number:")
number1 = int(text1)
text2 = input("What number do you want to skip:")
number2 = int(text2)

def count_down_skip(start, skip=0):

    
    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) if num != skip]


print("... ".join(map(str, count_down_skip(5, 3))) + "!")

def yes_or_no(question):
    reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
    if reply[0] == 'y':
        return 1
    elif reply[0] == 'n':
        return 0
    else:
        return yes_or_no("Please only input Y or N. ")


while True:
    # DRAW PLOT HERE;
    if(yes_or_no('Do you have more numbers to skip')):
      
        break
text3 = input("What number do you want to skip:")
number3 = int(text2)

def count_down_skip(start, skip=0):
    """
    Counting down a sequence with a skip value,
    from a defined start point in reversed order.

    Args:
        start: start loop index.
        skip: number to skip over.

    Returns:
        (list): skipped list.

    """
    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) if num != skip]


print("... ".join(map(str, count_down_skip(5, 1))) + "!")

def yes_or_no(question):
    reply = str(input(question+' (y/n): ')).lower().strip()
    if reply[0] == 'y':
        return 0
    elif reply[0] == 'n':
        return 1
    else:
        return yes_or_no("Please only input Y or N. ")


while True:
    # DRAW PLOT HERE;
    if(yes_or_no('Do you have more numbers to skip')):
        break
print("Alex is starting to count from 5") 
print("start")

#print("... ".join(map(str, count_down_skip(5, 1))) + "!")

def count_down_skip(start, skip = []):
    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) if num not in skip]

print("... ".join(map(str,count_down_skip(5,[1,3]))) + "!")

def count_down_skip(start, skip=0):

    return [num for num in reversed(range(start + 1)) if num not in skip]


print("... ".join(map(str, count_down_skip(10, [1,4,3]))) + "!")
```

And I think if I want to skip some numbers like from 10 to 0 without 1 4 3, I should use something like number() or int(), right? anyone can assist to change my code? It can work but a little bit imperfect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nice try, this is how I would do it, see below:

```
def main():
    skipable = set()

    name = input("What is your name?")
    max_number = input("What number do you want to count down from?")
    if type(int(max_number)) != int:
        raise Exception('You done messed up, please enter an integer next time')
    max_number = int(max_number)
    skipping = True
    while skipping:
        skip = input("Would you like to skip any numbers in the count down? Y/N")
        if skip == 'Y':
            number_to_skip = input("What number would you like to skip")
            try:
                number_to_skip = int(number_to_skip)
                skipable.add(number_to_skip)
            except Exception as e:
                print('Try entering an integer next time')
        elif skip == 'N':
            skipping = False
        else:
            print('Please Enter Y or N')

    numbers_to_print = [i for i in range(0, max_number+1) if i not in skipable]
    print(f'{name} is counting:')
    numbers_to_print.sort(reverse=True)
    print('...'.join(map(str, numbers_to_print)) + '!')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

results look like this:

```
What is your name?>? James
What number do you want to count down from?>? 5
Would you like to skip any numbers in the count down? Y/N>? Y
What number would you like to skip>? 2
Would you like to skip any numbers in the count down? Y/N>? N
James is counting:
5...4...3...1...0!
```

EDIT
Oh and if you want it to count down, you could down just throw a:

```
numbers_to_print.sort(reverse=True)
```

in there and it will sort the list descending.

Edit 2.  Changed the code above to match question better

Comment: You are so excellent! it works out well. And I added numbers_to_print.sort(reverse=True). But if I hope the out put format is 5...4...2...0! the print should be print("... ".join(map(str,i)))+ "!")  right?!

Comment: I try to use print("... ".join(map(str,main(i)))+ "!")  but the error happened....

Comment: the map function takes a function and an itterable, let me change the code above

Comment: Have changed the code above, try that.  Does that make sense why that works now?

Comment: You are the best!!!!! it works out!  Thank you soooooooo much! May all lucky things around you forever and ever and ever!